# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdf

Tags: makefile, fortran90

I am facing a problem, 
When I am using Makefile to install a software, I am getting this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lg2c
```

When I am searching libg2c

Its showing the path:

```
/home/guest/Downloads/mdsplus/math/libg2c.a
/home/initm03/Desktop/mdsplus/math/libg2c.a
/home/initm03/Downloads/mdsplus/math/libg2c.a
/usr/local/mdsplus/math/libg2c.a
```

Please so the needful if possible

Answer (score 0):

The linker needs to know where to look for the library.

use the `--library-path` commandline switch or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to specify the path of your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In the makefile, you'll need to tell the linker where to find libg2c;

Change

```
-lg2c
```

in the linker options in the makefile to;

```
-L/usr/local/mdsplus/math -lg2c
```

...and it should be able to find it and link correctly.